# How do I restart a service at every reboot?

Tags: linux, boot, redhat-enterprise-linux

As a result of a bug in mcollective [1], I need to restart the service immediately after each boot. What is the best way to accomplish this?

[1] https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=906885

Comment: How about using a crontab task with the @reboot param? Details here: http://www.linuxandlife.com/2013/01/how-to-use-crontab-to-schedule-tasks.html

Comment: What kind of bug?  Can you reliably check for the buggy behavior with a simple test?  If yes, then just write a script that tests to see if mcollective is 'working', if not restart, set cron to run it every 5 minutes or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a line for restart in /etc/rc.local (/etc/rc.d/rc.local)? It is started at last script after boot. So just add a

> /etc/init.d/mcollective restart

in it.

Comment: That is perfect, thank you @fede.evol. For the next guy... https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Installation_Guide/s1-boot-init-shutdown-run-boot.html